# How to shorten url to show domain only with angular.js filter

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I got some long urls in my Json and I'm trying to figure out the best way to show only the domain using angular's filter or maybe just some javascript ?

http://www.example.com/page-with-a-long-long-long-OMG-so-long-name.html

to

www.example.com

thank you !

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's really easy in AngularJS to create your own filter:

```js
app.filter( 'domain', function () {
  return function ( input ) {
    var matches,
        output = "",
        urls = /\w+:\/\/([\w|\.]+)/;

    matches = urls.exec( input );

    if ( matches !== null ) output = matches[1];

    return output;
  };
});
```

Which you can easily call in your view:

```html
<span>{{ myUrl | domain }}</span>
```

Here's a Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/bVSv7n?builder&p=preview

This is a super-simple regex that you'll probably want to expand, but it works!

Comment: That's what I'm looking for, thanks.
Just need to be sure that there is no better way to do this.

Comment: The above regex doesn't account for hyphens in domains

Comment: pipe is not needed inside the brackets. As per @dmur ```/\w+:\/\/([\w\.-]+)/```

Answer (score 7):

This angular filter will also work!

It is really cool and simple because it makes use of of the browsers built in URI parsing capability instead of relying on a regex.

```
angular.module('myCoolApp')
  .filter('urlFilter', function ($document) {
    return function (input) {
      var parser = document.createElement('a');
      parser.href = input;
      return parser.hostname;
  };
});
```

You can implement it in your view like this.

```
{{ myLongURL | urlFilter }}
```

If `myLongURL` is http://www.example.com/page-with-a-long-long-long-OMG-so-long-name.html, then it will show up as `example.com` after it passes through the filter. If you want the `www.` at the beginning you can just do this!

```
www.{{myLongURL | urlFilter}}
```

Comment: Do you know how i can combine this with linky? I want to add a text which can contains URLs. On view, I just want to display shortened URLs as linky, within the text..

Answer (score 0):

Use [`location.hostname`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.location) to get the domain without an accruements.

http://fiddle.jshell.net/TUeJ7/

Comment: my bad, my question wasn't well detailled. It's all about URL from referrer that I get in a Json. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I created this filter

```
angular.module('App').filter( 'domainOfUrl',['$filter',function ($filter) {
  return function ( input ) {
     var urlParts = input.split('/');      
    return urlParts[2];
  };
}]);
```

The above filter works like this:

input : `https://www.amazon.in/b/ref=s9_acss_bw_***_x`

output: `www.amazon.in`

**use `$filter` if you want.**