# Shortening Linky in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm using Linky to make my ng-binds include link refs. However, sometimes my users dump links that have extremely long URLs that are often wider than the divs that contain them. I would like to do something like "http://Some.ReallyLong.com/URL/Thats/Way/Too/Long/For/The/Div/That/Should/Contain/it/called/SomeFile.jpg" to "http://Some.Really.com/.../SomeFile.jpg".

What's the best way to do that? Is there a way to run some text filter on top of Linky?

Right now I have

```
<p ng-bind-html="comment.Body | linky"></p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you can chain filters so

```
<p ng-bind-html="comment.Body | linky | customfilter"></p>
```

You are most likely going to have to do some regex magic to get the filtering you want.  Following article would be a good start to start from the domain side.

[How to shorten url to show domain only with angular.js filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14594965/how-to-shorten-url-to-show-domain-only-with-angular-js-filter)

Comment: This is exactly what I'm looking for! Thanks!

actually, I might end up just making ShortLinky and reimplement the whole thing. It's fairly simple... just don't trust myself to do it super securely =/

Comment: @greenfox If you like the answer can you pick it as the solution, glad I could help.

Comment: I *believe* this is the answer. Now I'm not so sure. I haven't had time to work on it, but I'll be back here if I have problems, so I'm marked it for now.